# https redirect with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I wanted all my domains (`http-www`, `http-non-www` and also `https-non-www`) be redirected to `HTTPS-WWW-example-com`

My `.htaccess` code seems to be working, but I really don't know how to check it. I am very doubtful if it works OK because google WMT indexes a lot of pages separately and that's for sure that something is wrong. I really want to avoid too much redirects which it seems to be the case

Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Please guys if this code happens not to be good and you send me another  one please write whole domain in it because I'm beginner and might screw something up. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond % { SERVER_PORT } 80
RewriteRule ^ (. * )$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should work for yah!

Comment: thank you Blessed Nerd, but this one doesn't seem to work for me at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

I would suggest instead relying on .htaccess, you should change domain's vhost config and redirect domains accordingly.